# What does it mean to "add files in a directory recursively"?

Tags: git, recursion

The Git book I'm reading online has the following line that confuses me:

> The git add command takes a path name for either a file or a directory; if it’s a directory, the command adds all the files in that directory recursively.

All of that makes sense except for the word "recursively". How is adding files in a directory recursively different than just adding files in a directory?

Comment: What if one of the file in your directory is a directory ?

Comment: It means it will also recurse into subdirectories and add those files.

Comment: Had to edit your title and question to match the quote. There is no adding _to_ a directory, it's files _from_ a directory _to_ source control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `git add` is invoked on a folder, it will traverse the directory structure to add all the files within the sub-folders of that particular "parent" folder.